# c++ windows application Static text over edit window

Tags: c++, static, edit

Hello i am making my first windows application code.

I want to know how can i make a CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC") child window, inside my main window, in which when the user clicks to add text on it,i want the
     CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT(***"REPORT"***)  "REPORT" text to dissapear.
(Some of the text is in greek)

Example: like this "Email or username" and "password" texts, that dont interrupt the user
https://www.codecademy.com/login?redirect=about%3A%2F%2Fblank

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch(Message) {

    case WM_COMMAND:{

        break;
    }



    case WM_CREATE:{
        HMENU hMenubar= CreateMenu();
        HMENU hFile= CreateMenu();
        HMENU hOptions= CreateMenu();

        AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFile, "File");
        AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, NULL, "Edit");
        AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hOptions, "Options");

        AppendMenu(hFile, MF_STRING, NULL, "Open");         
        AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, "Correction");            
        AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, "Search");            


        SetMenu(hwnd,hMenubar);


        CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT(""), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            10, 10, 200, 30,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_NAMEBOX, NULL, NULL
            );

        CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("NAME"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            10, 10, 200, 30,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_VNAMEBOX, NULL, NULL
            );

        CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("CALL1"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            220, 10, 200, 30,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_CALLBOX, NULL, NULL
            );

        CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("CALL2"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            220, 50, 200, 30,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_CALLBOX, NULL, NULL
            );

        CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("REPORT"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            10, 90, 410, 100,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_REPORTBOX, NULL, NULL
            );

        hwnd= CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("SUBMIT"), 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            55, 50, 100, 30,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_SUBMITBOX, NULL, NULL
            );




        break;
    }



    /* Upon destruction, tell the main thread to stop */
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    /* All other messages (a lot of them) are processed using default procedures */
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Hans! But i am looking for an example on the web, i find lots of them, but i do not understand them, and i also dont know where do they put this code in the whole c++ file.

Can you, or someone else show me a valid example in the code i posted?